# Combine Default Experience Editor Buttons and Custom Buttons

Tags: experience-editor

When rendering an image field inside of a link field the experience editor buttons for the two fields collapse into one toolbar. Is it possible to do something similar with an edit frame rendered around a field with experience editor buttons? Example would be an edit frame with the move up and move down buttons that has a link field rendered inside of it:

```
@using (Html.EditFrame(Model.Item.ID.ToString(), "path/to/buttons", "Title", "Tooltip", 
"", null)))
{
   @Html.Sitecore().Field("Link", Model.Item)
}
```

I tried passing parameters of `new { haschildren = true }` instead of null but that didn't seem to change things. My current workaround is to use a field editor button which is fine but I'd want to know if there's another way to deal with it.